# Вылетает программа с рекурсией после запаковки в exe ( PyQT5 )

Tags: python, pyqt5, selenium, рекурсия, pyinstaller

Есть программа на PyQT5 с рекурсией, при запуске в IDE работает нормально, но версия, запакованная pyinstaller вылетает после 605 циклов с такой ошибкой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал на разных операционных системах, компах с разной конфигурацией, менял sys.setrecursionlimit, без толку, на 605 циклах вылет.
Что можно сделать?

Comment: `Что можно сделать?` Опубликовать минимально-воспроизводимый пример, иначе ваш вопрос не имеет смысла.

Comment: опубликуйте код хотя бы.

Comment: У самого питона довольно жёсткие ограничения по рекурсии. Я когда экспериментировал, вроде sys.setrecursionlimit можно до 1500 где-то поднять, но это не панацея. Странно, что не подействовало в вашем случае. В любом случае от рекурсии лучше избавиться, если это не в подключаемых библиотеках такая проблема, а у вас в программе.

Comment: @n1tr0xs https://github.com/VlatekSoft/test/

Comment: @S.Nick https://github.com/VlatekSoft/test/

Comment: @CrazyElf но почему тогда в IDE нормально работает? А exe вылетает?

Comment: @Vladislav Не знаю, возможно разные версии питона при этом используются. Не редко в системе туча разных питонов сидит и пойди пойми какой где запускается и из какой среды.

Comment: @CrazyElf у меня только одна Python 3.7.2 x64

Comment: А в логах виндоуза нет никакой инфы о конкретной ошибке приложения?

Comment: я давно не запускал программы в IDE. Как ведет ваш `код.py`, если его запустить из командной строк ( CMD ) ?  `python main.py`

Comment: @S.Nick все таки прекращает работу на 1253 цикле. Ну я работаю в VS, там тот же терминал запускается

Comment: Какой командой вы компилируете код ?

Comment: У вас же qt - рекурсию перепишите на цикл и тело цикла положите в main loop

Comment: @n1tr0xs в VS через дебаггер

Comment: @eri уже переписал, но вопрос с рекурсией все равно открыт

Comment: попробуйте скомпилировать этой командой через `cmd`: `pyinstaller -F main.py -w -p "D:\QtDesigner\Qt5Core.dll"` Путь к файлу замените на ваш